# How to Detect Hardware Acceleration for OpenGL on Windows

Tags: winapi, opengl, hardware, hardware-acceleration

Is there a Win32 API call that detects the current hardware acceleration level of a user's system?  I have no need to change the setting, but I'd like to scale back the level of detail for my OpenGL display if hardware acceleration is disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the FAQ: [How do I know my program is using hardware acceleration on a Wintel card?](http://web.archive.org/web/20120306065059/http://www.opengl.org/resources/faq/technical/mswindows.htm#0030)

> If you are using the Win32 interface (as opposed to GLUT), call `DescribePixelFormat()` and check the returned `dwFlags` bitfield. If `PFD_GENERIC_ACCELERATED` is clear and `PFD_GENERIC_FORMAT` is set, then the pixel format is only supported by the generic implementation. Hardware acceleration is not possible for this format. For hardware acceleration, you need to choose a different format.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can interrogate the device's capability with [Direct3D](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb172513%28VS.85%29.aspx), if you're on Windows.  The ["standard" GDI Win32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144877%28VS.85%29.aspx) GetDeviceCaps() call doesn't deal with 3D...